# JavaScript -- 0.56 + 4 = 4.5600000000000005

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Just had fun tracking down this weird glitch.  You can open up console and type in `0.56 + 4` which will give you `4.5600000000000005` in JavaScript.  I'm using `Chrome Version 26.0.1410.43`

Haven't tried in other browsers.

I know about rounding error but what's going on here exactly?

Comment: Binary floating point math.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem

Comment: If you don't understand what's going on here, you don't "know about rounding error".

Comment: I didn't realize it could happen at such a high level / small amount of decimal places.